# Element name as value of an attribute. (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

For example i have a structure in xml document:

```
<anything type="holiday">
   text
</anything>
```

After transformation i would like it to be like:

```
<holiday></holiday>
```

How can it be done? I have been surfing the net and didn't find any solution.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`xsl:element` constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#xsl-element), and in the `@name` where you specify the name of the element, use an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#dt-attribute-value-template) and apply the value of the `@value` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@type]">
  <xsl:element name="{@type}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```